# Why do potential difference between the terminals of an ideal battery remains equal to its $Emf$ even if it is connected externally

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, batteries

In an ideal battery, the battery forces are equal in magnitude to the electric forces (the ones that are present when battery is  not connected externally) and thus we conclude that E.M.F. ($\varepsilon$) of an ideal battery equals the potential difference between its terminals when terminals are not connected externally

$$\varepsilon=\frac{F_bd}{q}$$
$$F_b=qE_*$$
$$\varepsilon=E_*d=V$$

$F_b=$ battery force,
$d=$ distance between terminals,
$V=$ petential difference between the terminals,
$E_*=$ electric field between terminals when not connected externally

Now when we connect the terminals externally the electric forces tends to decrease(due to flow of charges externally) and $F_b$ dominates and due to this difference the charges flow inside the battery too. Now my question is if the magnitude of electric forces becomes less than the $F_b$ (which is same as earlier) then $V(=Ed)$ should also decrease (since $E$ decreases). Then why do we say and eventually do calculations by considering that the potential difference between the terminals of an ideal battery remains equal to its $\varepsilon$ even if it is connected externally.

Since I'm a new learner so I may be wrong somewhere in the understanding of battery. Please correct me if I'm wrong so that I can better understand the concepts

Comment: Why does E decrease?

Comment: @user253751  since charges flow externally thus reducing $E$ inside battery and this make $F_b$ relatively stronger and there’s current inside battery too.

Comment: Do you know what "ideal" means?